# "plaintext" vs "plain text"?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I am creating identifiers in so called "camel case". This means that words are concatenated together and all the words (except the first in our case) are started with a capital letter.

For example, "see also" becomes `seeAlso`.

For "plaintext" or "plain text" it becomes `plaintext` or `plainText`.

So "plaintext" or "plain text"? (and thus `plaintext` or `plainText`?).

Side note: The term "plain text" means a text without formatting (without bold, italic, color, etc.)

Comment: What is your actual question? You hint at it in the title—but you don't actually ask it in the body of your question, which is just showing how camel case works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Plaintext* as a single word in the software industry is used to mean "not encrypted."

If you simply mean unformatted text, you should use `plainText`.

Even better is being more specific and using `unformattedText`.

Comment: I agree with this answer—but I'm not sure if it answers the question, since I don't know what the question actually is . . . (If it's a single word, then nothing is capitalized; if it's two words, then the first letter of the concatenated portion is capitalized.)